# Autoscrolling slide javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

I have This javascript code for a slider that I downloaded , and can't figure out how to make it auto scrolling !!
I actually downloaded this code from http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/index2.html
It actually don't contain a next button so i can add an interval like the other sliders :(

```
$(function() {
    var Page = (function() {
        var $nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
        slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
            onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {
                $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
            }
        } ),

        init = function() {
            initEvents();
            setInterval(initEvents,1000);
        },

        initEvents = function() {
            $nav.each( function( i ) {
                $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
                    var $dot = $( this );

                    if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {
                        $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                        $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                    }

                    slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
                    return false;
                } );
            } );

        };
        return { init : init };
    })();

    Page.init();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it says [in the docs](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/) (Google is helpful):

```
slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider({
    autoplay : true
});
```

should do it.

If you don't want to read the whole thing, here's a short list of common config options:

```
$.Slitslider.defaults   = {
// transitions speed
speed : 800,
// if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
optOpacity : false,
// amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
translateFactor : 230,
// maximum possible angle
maxAngle : 25,
// maximum possible scale
maxScale : 2,
// slideshow on / off
autoplay : false,
// keyboard navigation
keyboard : true,
// time between transitions
interval : 4000,
// callbacks
onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; },
onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; }
};
```